# Opencart 3 route not working, but it should

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I'm trying to create a route in Opencart 3, but don't know why it's not working. When going to that route it gives 404 Page not found. But it is simple and it should work. At least I think so :). Maybe I am missing something. Here's the code:

```
class ControllerCsvCsv extends Controller {

public function index() {

    header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="amby_products.csv"');

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');
    $this->load->model('catalog/category');

    $products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();


    $csvArray[0] = array(
        'id',
        'image_link',
        'title',
        'category',
        'price',
        'inventory_tracking',
        'availability',
        'link',
        'brand',
        'google_product_category',
        'desciption',
        'condition'
    );

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $category = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product['product_id']);
        $url = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']);
        foreach ($category as $cat) {
            $getCategory = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($cat['category_id']);
        }

        $csvArray[] = array(
            $product['product_id'],
            $product['image'],
            $product['name'],
            $getCategory['name'],
            $product['special'] ? $product['special'] : $product['price'],
            $product['quantity'],
            $product['stock_status'],
            $url,
            $product['manufacturer'],
            $getCategory['name'],
            null,
            'new'
        );
    }


    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ($csvArray as $line) {
        fputcsv($fp, $line, ',');
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

}

Url that should work https://domain/index.php?route=csv/csv

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code above into a blank OC3 test environment and had no trouble with it.  If you are getting a 404 that means there is some other aspect of your config causing the issue that's not relayed here - and it's unrelated to the above code.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `class ControllerCsvCsv extends Controller {` you said to Opencart that your controller is in catalog/controller/csv/csv.php are you sure your file is there? Everything is OK with your code, so i think that your controller is not at right place, can you show your where is your file (csv.php) ?

Comment: Yes, it is that place catalog/controller/csv/csv.php. That is really strange, cant figure out why not working, even if all is correct

Comment: Please, post an image with directory structure?

Comment: Are you sure, csv directory and csv file have read rights  - 755 / 644 ?